# Showing all changes for a key record from another table

Tags: mysql

Given these two tables

```
subject               subject_changes
-----------            ------------------
id                     id   
subjectName           version           
subjectCode           subjectCode
version               previousSubjectCode
```

How do I show all changes in the subjectCode? I have to refer to subjectCode based on previousSubjectCode and get the relevant data for that version.

In subject table, I have

```
1, 'Animals','Q001', 1
2, 'Animal Kingdom', 'Q012',2 
2, 'Animal Kingdom', 'Q023',3
```

and in subject_changes

```
1, 2, 'Q012', 'Q001'
2, 3, 'Q023', 'Q012'
```

In pseudo code

```
SELECT * FROM subject WHERE subjectCode= ?

SELECT * FROM subject_changes WHERE subjectCode=?

foreach subjectCode 
   get previousSubjectCode
   get subjectName from subject table

SELECT * FROM subject WHERE subjectCode = subject_changes.previousSubjectCode
```

the result table should look like

```
version   subjectName     subjectCode
-------   -----------      ---------- 
version 3 Animal Kingdom  Q023  
version 2 Animal Kingdom  Q012
version 1 Animal          Q001
```

Comment: What does `subject_changes.id` represent: the `subject.id`? It is hard to tell from your example, because two of the `subject` records have the same id (ie 2). Is that a typo?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    subject.version, subject.subjectName, subject.subjectCode
FROM subject
INNER JOIN subject_changes USING (subjectCode)
WHERE subjectCode = ?
```

Comment: Thanks, but the query would return all records instead of just one record and it's related changes. I'll edit the question to make it clear since I realize that I do not need to use the version table in this case.

Comment: Then just add a `WHERE` clause.

Comment: This query will return just the subject without it's related changes. The previousSubjectCode refers to another row in the subject table which the query needs to return.

Comment: Then add that in the `SELECT`. It's simple. Your example output in the OP only includes `version`, `subjectName`, and `subjetCode`, so that's what I've shown. I'm not going to keep changing my answer every time you change the question. I'm not going to do all the work for you. I've given you enough above for you to work with without difficulty.

Comment: Changes in the question doesn't affect the results that I'm aiming from the start. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: We're not mind readers. We can only answer the question you give. Even now you say at the end of the OP "the result table should look like: `version`, `subjectName`, `subjectCode`.". So that's what my answer provides.